# how to import python modules in folders to list

Tags: python, python-import

I'm trying to get a list of all the mods that I have for a fun project I'm working on but I can't figure out how to get it to work I have already researched this for a couple of hours and couldn't understand how to do it.

Here is my code

```
dirs = os.listdir('Assets/mods/scripts/')
    for i in range(len(dirs)):
        if not dirs[i].endswith('.py'):
            continue
        try:
            mods.append(importlib.__import__('Assets.mods.scripts.' + dirs[i].removesuffix('.py')))
        except Exception as e:
            print('importing error:\n', e)
```

Every time I can see that it imports it (it prints a few numbers to the console) but when I try to use anything in the module by using this function:

```
    for i in range(len(mods)):
        try:
            mods[i].update()
        except Exception as e:
            print('updating error:\n', e)
```

It just doesn't call the functions and tells me:

```
updating error:
 module 'Assets' has no attribute 'update'
```

Comment: what do you have in modules? Maybe they don't have `update()`?

Comment: @furas i do have an update function in there its ```print(17)
def update():
    print('it works')```

Comment: figured it out i needed this in the function ```fromlist=['Assets/mods']```

Answer (score -1):

```
import os
import importlib.util

def import_modules_from_folder(folder_path):
    module_list = []
    for file_name in os.listdir(folder_path):
        if file_name.endswith('.py') and not file_name.startswith('__init__'):
            module_name = file_name[:-3]  # Remove '.py' extension
            module_list.append(module_name)
            module_path = os.path.join(folder_path, file_name)
            spec = importlib.util.spec_from_file_location(module_name, module_path)
            module = importlib.util.module_from_spec(spec)
            spec.loader.exec_module(module)
    return module_list

if __name__ == "__main__":
    # Specify the path to the folder containing modules
    my_modules_folder = 'my_modules'
    other_modules_folder = 'other_modules'

    # Import modules from folders
    my_modules_list = import_modules_from_folder(my_modules_folder)
    other_modules_list = import_modules_from_folder(other_modules_folder)

    # Print the lists
    print("My Modules:", my_modules_list)
    print("Other Modules:", other_modules_list)
```

Comment: you should describe answer

Comment: @yash portal i want to store the module itself in a list not the name i want to be able to run functions from that list later

Comment: figured it out i needed this in the import ```fromlist=['Assets/mods']```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).